# Aligning an actively-rendered JPanel inside a JFrame

Tags: java, rendering, jframe, jpanel, bufferedimage

Can anybody explain why pack() isn't working on this JFrame?

It's got one JPanel inside (actually, a class that extends JPanel - `inner`).

Here's the code I'm using:

```
inner.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
add(inner);
pack();
setResizable(false);
setLocationRelativeTo(null); // to center the JFrame on screen
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);
```

The extra space seems to be the exact width and height of the JFrame's decoration (that is, the JFrame's dimensions minus the JPanel's dimensions).

[image]

Comment: The extra space is visible in gray on the bottom and right sides of the JFrame.  If the contrast is too low, I can post another image.

Comment: did you try by toggling `setUndecorated(boolean v)`?

Comment: I'd like to keep the decoration.  But if you're curious, the size of the undecorated window is more accurate (though, oddly, off by a few pixels -- according to my measurement).

Comment: *"I can post another image."*  Before you consider that, please check the tips in [How do I create ScreenShots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post), especially the advice about 'alt+printscreen' and 400x300 when it shows the effect!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Is there something wrong with the screenshot I posted?

Comment: See my answer for a solution.  The problem was with double-buffered active rendering, and not pack().

Comment: `JPanel` is double-buffered by default; I'm surprised you need [active rendering](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html).

Comment: I'm working with agent-based simulation, so it can get quite expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was drawing (active rendering) from the JFrame and not the JPanel... so the extra space was the result of the JPanel's draw() object being aligned at 0,0 (in the JFrame).

Solved by [this post](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=15077.msg119781#msg119781).

Answer (score 3):

Invoke `setResizable(false)` *before* `pack()`. It's no coincidence that "extra space seems to be the exact width and height of the `JFrame`'s decoration."

Addendum: Here's an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) showing that my initial guess was incorrect.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924830 */
public class NonResizable extends JPanel {

    public NonResizable() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        this.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("NonResizable");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setBackground(Color.white);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setSize(500, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NonResizable().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If that's not helpful, please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: It removes some of the space, but not all of it.  I'll work on getting an sscce together.

Comment: My initial guess was wrong; I've added an example above.